# whats information is stored inside a device file in linux

Tags: linux, device

I want to know what information is actually stored inside a device file in linux.
Like we have many nodes inside /dev directory representing a device .
But what is actually contained inside those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device file nodes under `/dev` are not actually files; they don't "contain" any data. Rather, they are interfaces that the Linux kernel (or a kernel module) provides and that you can use to talk with the kernel from a program.

Some of the nodes correspond to a hardware device, like `/dev/sda` (hard disk) or `/dev/video0` (webcam or other video source), while others exist purely in software, like `/dev/null`, or `/dev/ptmx`. How each device node is used depends on the device type.